# How can I get the hex value of an 8 row column with depending on background color?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using to help visualize a character bit map for each ASCII character.  For a 5x7 font, I use 5 cells wide (columns) and 7 cells tall (rows).  I then marked the background black for each cell in a 8 row column, to represent the bits of a byte, where each bit is a pixel, and a black background means a pixel that is `ON`.  Then, I create a byte array which will be my character representation.  I have to do this for 95 characters (ASCII values), for each font size I want.

The problem is that I have to stare at each column of the character, and determine its binary value and then figure out the hex value.  So trying to figure out 495 bytes for a 5-wide character table becomes tedious work.  I want to know if there is a worksheet function I could write that would inspect the background color of a cell, if black is would set the *n*th bit of a variable, and then create the hex value of that column below.

**TL;DR** I don't have function writing experience in Excel. I'm working with a LCD screen. I have a spreadsheet with all my characters on it--where each pixel that is `ON` would have the background color of black.  1 cell = 1 bit of a byte. I need a function that will give me a hex value of a column depending if the background cell is black or not.  Proceed to illustrations.

Here is an example of a 5x7 character 'A' in my spreadsheet.  A *** represents that a cells background color is black, otherwise white.  (It wouldn't be a problem to add something like a cell value of 1 to each cell that has a background color of black if needed, to make this an easier function):

```
   ____________________
B0|   |***|***|***|   | (row 0)
  |-------------------|
B1|***|   |   |   |***| (row 1)
  |-------------------|
B2|***|   |   |   |***| (row 2)
  |-------------------|
B3|***|***|***|***|***| (row 3)
  |-------------------|
B4|***|   |   |   |***| (row 4)
  |-------------------|
B5|***|   |   |   |***| (row 5)
  |-------------------|
B6|***|   |   |   |***| (row 6)
  |-------------------|
B7|___|___|___|___|___| (row 7)
   7E  09  09  09  7E   (row 8)
```

The byte array would then be:

```
byte A[] = { 0x7E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x7E };
```

Pseudo-code version (for one column):

```
char hex = 0x00;
for(int bI = 0; bI < 8; bI++)
{
    if(cell[bI].BackgroundColor == Black)
    {
        hex |= (0x01 << bI;
    }
}
row8.Text = hex.ToString("X2");
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you have and what you need.  Are you starting with a concept and a magnifying glass?  So are you looking for a solution that involves reading the Windows font files?  (You might want to consider displaying all the characters (e.g., in Notepad or Word), taking a screen snapshot, pasting into Paint, saving the image, and then analyzing the image file.)  Or do you already have the { 0x7E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x7E } data, and you just need help displaying it?

Comment: being that the tags have all to do with excel, I figured the question was rather straightforward--I needed a worksheet function. the marked answer solves my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a column to indicate the bit positions & add the number of `1`s (bits). For my example below, what I did was:

1. Create a conditional format for my 5x7 range, where if I enter `1` into a cell, it turns black (I used orange so I can see the 1's).

   [image]
2. Add a column to the left of the character to mark the bit positions in decimal `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`, `32`, `64`  (see column B).
3. To get the hex values, use this formula across bottom:

   `=DEC2HEX(SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8,D2:D8),2)`

   [image]

   Where:

   - **$B$2:$B$8** is the range that contains the bit positions in decimal
   - **D2:D8** is the first column in the 5x7 range
   - **2** is the number of digits you want to display

---

If you don't wish to create an extra column, incorporate the bit positions into the formula, like so:

```
=DEC2HEX(SUMPRODUCT({1;2;4;8;16;32;64},G1:G7),2)
```

Ex:
[image]

<sub>ref http://www.computerhope.com/binhex.htm</sub>